# How do I set up cross-block variables in PUG 3 templates?

Tags: pug

I have a pug like this:

```
extends layout.pug

block a

  - var x = 'test'

  //- stuff

block b

  //- ..... stuff
```

Which works great.

But when I try to move the  `- var x` thing for both `block a` and `block b`, I failed.

I tried this:

```
extends layout.pug

- var x = 'test'

block a


  //- stuff

block b

  //- ..... stuff
```

It says:

> Only named blocks and mixins can appear at the top level of an extending template

And this:

```
- var x = 'test'

extends layout.pug

block a


  //- stuff

block b

  //- ..... stuff
```

It says:

> Declaration of template inheritance ("extends") should be the first thing in the file. There can only be one extends statement per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mentioned in the [*Template Inheritance > Common mistakes* section of the Pug docs](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html#common-mistakes), along with two potential solutions:

> Note that **only named blocks and mixin definitions** can appear at the top (unindented) level of a child template. This is important! Parent templates define a page’s overall structure, and child templates can only `append`, `prepend`, or replace specific blocks of markup and logic. If a child template tried to add content outside of a block, Pug would have no way of knowing where to put it in the final page.
>
> This includes [unbuffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code), which can also contain markup. If you need to define variables for use in a child template, you can do so a few different ways:
>
> - Add the variables to the Pug [options](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#options) object, or define them in unbuffered code in a parent template. The child template will inherit these variables.
> - Define the variables *in a block* in the child template. Extending templates must have at least one block, or it would be empty — just define your variables there.